# How do I convert this LINQ query expression from C# to VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, c#-to-vb.net

I have the following C# LINQ query expression:

```
var duplicatedSSN =
         from p in persons
         group p by p.SSN into g
         where g.Count() > 1
         select g.Key;
```

Can anyone help me convert this to VB.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim duplicateSSN = From p in persons _
                   Group By Key=p.SSN _
                   Into g = Group _
                   Where g.Count() > 1 _
                   Select Key
```